# Is Teemo better as an AP, AD, or Hybrid?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is Teemo better AP, AD, or Hybrid for a support teemo? I have wanted to try and play him as a support shroomer. As a support teemo would I want to get 40% CDR?

Comment: There's also a Debuffy build, isn't it? With madred, malady, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried AP build, AD build and also Hybrid for Teemo but unfortunately not a support role.

The AP build is just pure awesome to see your shrooms(/eggs or whatever skin you use) do over 1000 damage over (late game) and you're probably going to get a lot of QQ from other players about KS:ing when the enemies run across 1 of your shrooms. Through the entire game you're very squishy thou, so be sure to have some shrooms at your expected escape route.

The AD build with the % lifesteal you have is just sick, but early game you have to really play defensively.

The hybrid spec is as the above, pretty squishy early game if not played correctly, but the fast paste shots with the dot from Toxic Shot can't help to make you smile when you catch a squishy opponent.

Answer (score 1):

Teemo with high focus on AP can and will be very dangerous if the player can predict some paths the enemy team will take. Some good placement of shrooms can be devestating for the enemy team since they will do massive damage. Although Teemo is very squishy and dosen't have that much "support" abilitys but it can work really good. Also 40% CDR isn't nessecary from my experience, 20% is enough ( Each to their own )

Answer (score 1):

I play him this way:

- Boots of Swiftness
- Wriggles
- Wit's End
- Madres Bloodrazor
- Guinsoo Ragablade

OR

- Hextech Gunblade
- Ranbandon's Deathcap
- Rylai's Crystal Scepter
- Nashor's tooth
- Madred's bloodrazor/Frozen mallet

Or play with different items every time to see what suits you (your playstyle) the most. You may define his role according to the items I propose.

Answer (score 0):

Teemo is most certainly a hybrid works best with Atk speed and Ad mostly Wit' end, Frozen mallet and some ap will not hurt the little fury bastard where items like malady hex tech gun blade will benefit him well....

Answer (score 0):

As support Teemo, yeah, max CDR and AP are fantastic. Your enemies will be quickly frustrated and lose their edge. At least in my experience! :D Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

As far as support champions go teemo is not the best choice, but if used in that role. I would get CDR and attack speed (Wits End). Other items depend on your team comp and enemy comp.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid teemo is more usefull, in my opinion because he can do sustained damage throughout the fight, and if you build mallet you can be really tanky and kite easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of opinion but that is the intention of the question in the first place.  I like attack speed on-hit teemo.  Teemo is a far too hated champ that has global taunt.  The entire enemy team will begin running through the entire map to kill you or try to after running over a few of your mushrooms.  Sometimes, they'll do it even if they don't walk over the mushrooms due to personal trauma from previous encounters against teemo.  The most important thing is to not die, which means any of the builds that tries emphasizing damage is the wrong build.  Tanky teemo with frozen mallet works well.

Answer (score 0):

attack speed, frozen mallet, and bloodrazor work out really well, also a build used by one of the best teemos in the world, TheRainMan. guide http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=658

Answer (score 0):

1 word. Scaling , He has so much damage as AP user. Plus teemo's late game as a AD , is cancer . you put someone with a range like vaynes in team fight and can't make a huge impact other than blind 1 person , he has 0 cc escapes which is why he's preferred to be used as an AP